# Get the value of the HTML tag 'select' in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a project and I got to a part where I have to get the value of the HTML tag `<select>` in `PHP`.

My HTML code is the following:

```html
<div class="main-content">

      <form class="form-register" method="post" action="">

        <div class="form-register-with-email">

          <div class="form-white-background">

            <div class="form-title-row">
              <h1>Create an account</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
              <label>
                <span>Register As</span>
                <select name="register_as" id="dropdown">
                  <option value="none">Select One</option>
                  <option value="user">User</option>
                  <option value="designer">Designer</option>
                </select>
              </label>
            </div>

<div class="form-row" id="design1">
                        <label>
                            <span>Company Name</span>
                            <input type="text" name="name">
                        </label>
                    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
```

I affect the number of fields displayed by using the following jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#design1").hide();

      $("#dropdown").change(function() {

        if ($("#dropdown").val() == "designer") {
          $('.main-content').addClass('design'); // add this line
          $("#design1").show();
        } else {
          $('.main-content').removeClass('design'); // add this line
          $("#design1").hide();
      });

      if ($("#dropdown").val() == "designer") {

        $("#design1").show();

      }

    });
```

Now I am using this `PHP` script to get the value:

```css
<?php

 if(!empty($_POST)){
  
  $errors = array();


        if(isset($_POST['register_as']) AND ($_POST['register_as'] != 'user' OR $_POST['register_as'] != 'designer')){
            
            $errors['register_as'] = "Register as an user or a designer";
        }

        var_dump($_POST['register_as']);

 }

?>
```

The function `var_dump` displays the correct value. I mean, when `User` is selected from the dropdown, the `var_dump` displays `user`. The main problem is that I am get the error `Register as an user or a designer`

I do not really know what is going on.

Kindly help me solve this problem

Comment: use and instead of or. if `$_POST['register_as']` is `user`, then it's not `designer` and vice versa (the second condition of your if statement will always return true)

Answer (score 2):

your condition

```
isset($_POST['register_as']) AND ($_POST['register_as'] != 'user' OR $_POST['register_as'] != 'designer')
```

checking for `( $_POST['register_as'] != 'user' or $_POST['register_as'] )` then whenever you select any one option (user or designer) from the dropdown then at-least one condition must be true and the $_POST['register_as'] will be always true so the condition is always true and returns you error array

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['register_as']) && $_POST['register_as'] != 'none'){
   $errors['register_as'] = "Register as an user or a designer";
}
```

Comment: In case the user changes the HTML source code and set the value of one of the dropdown option to `adrian` for example, you code is still working. Hope you are getting the point I am trying to make

Comment: not much I am sorry.... what are you trying to achieve with PHP? why are you creating an array for errors?

Answer (score 0):

```css
<?php

 if(!empty($_POST)){
  
  $errors = array();

        // Should be like this
        if(isset($_POST['register_as']) AND ($_POST['register_as'] != 'user' AND $_POST['register_as'] != 'designer')){
            
            $errors['register_as'] = "Register as an user or a designer";
        }
        // Or like this:
        if(isset($_POST['register_as']) AND ($_POST['register_as'] == 'user' OR $_POST['register_as'] == 'designer')){
            
            $errors['register_as'] = "Register as an user or a designer";
        }

        var_dump($_POST['register_as']);

 }

?>
```